# PXE Boot Fedora 17 Error

Tags: linux, fedora, pxe-boot

When trying to boot into the latest Fedora 17 cd via PXE, I am presented with the following error:

```
PXE dracut: fatal: no or empty root= argument
```

So, I added a `root=` line to my fedora menu entry (shown below), but receive the following error:

```
dracut Warning: Unable to process initqueue
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

**Fedora.menu**

```
LABEL 1
    MENU LABEL fedora 17 (32-bit)
    KERNEL fedora/17/i386/vmlinuz0
    APPEND method=nfs:192.168.1.101:/srv/install/fedora/17/i386/ lang=us keymap=us ip=dhcp ksdevice=eth1 noipv6 root=/dev/ram0 initrd=fedora/17/i386/initrd0.img ramdisk_size=10000
    TEXT HELP
    Install Fedora 17 (32-bit)
    ENDTEXT
```

Comment: Try replacing the "method" with "root" cause I think it has been dropped in current dracut options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to help you, you'll can find in this URL: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?format=multiple&id=820366 a bug which can be compare to your problem.

I solved my problem by removing just an argument 'ksdevice=eth0' to my "APPEND" line:

The old one:

```
APPEND ks=http://xx/ks-fedora17-stations-local.cfg \
   initrd=images/fedora/x86_64/17/initrd.img \
   ramdisk_size=100000 ip=dhcp url --url ftp://xx/17/os ksdevice=eth0
```

The new one:

```
APPEND ks=http://xx/ks-fedora17-stations-local.cfg 
   initrd=images/fedora/x86_64/17/initrd.img \
   ramdisk_size=100000 ip=dhcp url --url ftp://xx/17/os
```

Hope this will help you.

Bests,